# Using Php-Xampp, MongoDB driver not located

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I apologize for asking this question since there are many similar to it on the site, but after following their advice, I am still at an impasse.

I am using Php 7.2.3 with Apache via Xampp, and Mongo 3.4. My Os is 64-bit Windows 10.  My Mongod server runs, and I can execute commands in the Mongo shell.  I have downloaded php_mongodb-1.4.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x64, and placed the php_mongodb.dll in my ext folder, and added extension=mongodb to my php.ini.  I have added to my System Path libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, php_mongodb.dll, and php.ini and restarted my computer.

Is it maybe that I'm missing an extension or commenting out one in php.ini that I need?  This is my extension list:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=mongodb
```

I've been googling for the last couple of days and none of the solutions I've tried seem to be working.  If anyone could please suggest some alternatives, I'd really appreciate it.  Thank you all so much for your time.

Comment: have you tried using full absolute path?

Comment: If you're referring to the path listed in System Variables, yes, I'm using the absolute path (ie. C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll ) :(

Comment: I mean actually in the .ini file so `extension=/full/path/to/.dll`

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly, no, that doesn't work either.  I wonder if it has something to do with Windows Administrative Control/Security?

Comment: hm interesting - not sure honestly, work in Linux :)